# Has anyone besides Egon Pearson accessed Gosset's 1904 paper?

Tags: statistical-significance, history

Has anyone besides Egon Pearson accessed William Sealy Gosset's 1904 report "The Application of the 'Law of Error' to the Work of the Brewery"? I guess it's Guinness property, but given its historical significance, it would have been a very interesting read, if someone were to know how to get their hands on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stephen Ziliak, an Economics professor at Roosevelt University in Chicago, has published a number of papers (and a book) on Gosset and related topics. See, for example, [this paper](http://economistsview.typepad.com/files/beeronomics-ziliak-guinness.pdf), which quotes the 1904 report you mention. In the references section, he cites 15 volumes of *Laboratory Reports*, which include Gosset's 1904 paper.

The Guinness web site says the archives are open to researchers by appointment; I wasn't able to find a digital copy of that particular paper.

Comment: I want to be the guy that shows up at the Guinness brewery, not for the beer, but for the science.  CrossValidated field trip?

Comment: I for one have never been a stout person, so I much prefer Guinness research to Guinness beer. I might actually make an inquiry with the company if I am ever going to Ireland.

Comment: @MatthewDrury All right guys, I'm going to a conference in Dublin next week, and can confirm that Guinness indeed seem to allow people (at least academics) into their archives.

Answer (score 2):

I just emailed them through their contact form https://www.guinness-storehouse.com/en/archives/archives-contact and I received a PDF copy. It's a very interesting read.

Comment: Interesting. I emailed them once and they told me to come in person if I wanted to see it. Since the document is long since public domain, could you post it online?

Comment: I got the following reply: 

Hi Daniel,

Thank you for your email. ‘The Application of the “Law of Error” to the work of the Brewery’ by WS Gosset is preserved within the Guinness Archive in a bound volume of laboratory reports – GDB/RD05/0010. I have shared a copy of the report with you through this link. Please note, the report is being shared with you for personal research only and should not be further shared or reproduced without first obtaining permission from the Guinness Archive.   

Best wishes,

Éilis


So, I can't share it. I don't think it is in the public domain.

Comment: It would be surprising for anything written in 1904 to still be copyright - there are some things like music or the King James Bible which can get weird, but they are definitely exceptions to the general rule of thumb that pre-1930 is PD. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_Ireland says 70 year from death of author, regardless of whether Gosset owned the copyright or it was a work-for-hire with copyright owned by Guinness (surely the latter). Gosset died in 1937, so the copyright expired in 2007, 15 years ago. You don't (legally) *need* their permission.

Comment: I think you misunderstand: It was never copyrighted. There is no copyright notice in the document, as the owner (Guinness) never intended to copy or distribute it in any way. They simply own it, and can let others read it (or not).

Comment: I went in person and got to see it for 20 minutes or so. Took some photographs of a couple of the reports, and that was it (they also made me promise not to share them). Interesting that they've opened the archive a bit more - a good move imo. It's perfectly reasonable that they don't want their company heritage released "into the wild" though. We should all respect that, regardless of copyright status.

Comment: If it was never copyrighted, then it's even *more* in the public domain, not less! The question here is can they stop you from redistributing the scan? The answer is 'no'. It was either always in the public domain or has been in PD for >15 years, and thus they have no copyright to enforce. They do not get a copyright by scanning it, per Corel vs Bridgman, so their digital version is also PD. You do not mention signing any legal contract and without consideration, it would be unenforceable, so no contract; you didn't agree to not reshare it before they sent it, so not even agreement. Thus...

Comment: I don't think your legal analysis is correct. The reason that I did not have to sign a contract is because some people are perfectly happy acting in a reasonable, good faith manner, and not wanting to ruin that way of working together as humans is exactly the reason I am adhering to their desires. It took me more time to reply to you here, than it took me to get the article from Guinness.

Comment: If you want to argue that on moral grounds you shouldn't, that's one thing; if you don't want to share it, simply say so. However, you are incorrect that they are capable of demanding permission or resharing restrictions, or that it is not in the public domain, you haven't given any grounds to think it is, and you shouldn't try to hide behind those claims as excuses.